# Inserting a value in HamsterDB with HAM_OVERWRITE

Tags: c++, hamsterdb

If I insert a value into a [HamsterDB](http://hamsterdb.com/) database with the flag `HAM_OVERWRITE`, what is the effect when the key doesn't already exists?

I am keeping track of the highest serial number in my program and persisting it in a HamsterDB database:

```
if (serial > high_serial_) {
    high_serial_ = serial;
    ham::key key((void*)HIGH_SERIAL_KEY, strlen(HIGH_SERIAL_KEY));
    ham::record record((void*)&high_serial_, sizeof(high_serial_));

    db.insert(&key, &record, HAM_OVERWRITE);
}
```

Upon starting up the application again, `high_serial_` is initialised with the current value stored in the DB:

```
ham::key key((void*)HIGH_SERIAL_KEY, strlen(HIGH_SERIAL_KEY));
auto record = roll_file_db.find(&key);
```

But this call is throwing `HAM_KEY_NOT_FOUND`. The [documentation](http://hamsterdb.com/public/scripts/html_www/group__ham__database.html#ga5bb99ca3c41f069db310123253c1c1fb) states that it will simply be inserted if the key doesn't already exist. This is not what I'm experiencing though.

Answer (score 0):

If the key does not exist and you call `ham_db_insert(db, txn, key, record, HAM_OVERWRITE)` then the key will be inserted.

If the key does not exist and you call `ham_db_find()` then you get `HAM_KEY_NOT_FOUND`.

The documentation for ham_db_find lists HAM_KEY_NOT_FOUND as a return value "if the key does not exist":
[http://hamsterdb.com/public/scripts/html_www/group_*ham*_database.html#ga90dd239b79be2181461bbabc2eee1496](http://hamsterdb.com/public/scripts/html_www/group__ham__database.html#ga90dd239b79be2181461bbabc2eee1496)

HTH
Christoph